# Node/Express: Mock a req.files when unzipping a dir

Tags: node.js, express

I'm extracting some files from a zip file with `Node/Express`. This library that extracts the files can write to disk or store the files in an array which contains a buffer of the data.

There is some code downstream thatinteracts with `Express/Multers` `req.files`, in that format. When a user doesn't upload a `zip`, this code gets what it needs. When a user uploads a zip, the content isn't in this form.

What are some approaches to handle such a case? I'm currently creating an array that has a similar shape as the the `req.files` based on the array that the `zip` library makes.

```
// If the payload is a `zip`, unzip and put the files on `req`
const unZippedFiles = await unZipFile(files[0].path, req);
req.files = unZippedFiles;
req.unzippedPath = unzippedPath;
```

this array of files has a different shape and different properties than the array produced by Multer..

```
// otherwise..just use multer to put files on req
const importFileHandler = multer({
  dest,
  preservePath: true,
  fileFilter: (_req, file, cb) => {
    if (fileFilter.isPermitted(file)) {
      return cb(null, true);
    }

    const err = new Error('file type is not allowed');
    return cb(null, false, err);
  }
}).any();
```

Comment: please post https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Post your program